# Graphical map objects representation website

Tags: javascript, python, django, leaflet

Sorry this question is too broad, but I need any advice, because I'm facing a task bit above my experience level.

The map should be displayed with database objects like restaurants/events/etc. The suggested platform is Python/Django (which is fine both for me and customer) for both frontend and backend. As a map itself I want to use [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) because its (presumably) flexible and free. In the first phase there should be just one toolbar with checkboxes, allowing to choose object types to be shown on the map and time range to choose objects.

My draft is the following:

- Leaflet (js based) as map
- use database for map objects with default Django admin first and add functionality when needed;
- use HTML and Django widgets for toolbar, checkboxes and all other stuff;

The only concern is about the frontend/widgets. Is it all likely to work this way?  Maybe its definetly better to switch to JS frontend for this type of application (as future planning)?

Answer (score 1):

Your plan seems solid.

> Maybe its definetly better to switch to JS frontend for this type of application (as future planning)?

You're already using JS with leaflet, so I assume you're asking about building your own or using a maps service API directly. That approach will take more time, and will lock you into the service API, so I would recommend against it.

Comment: No way I think of creating custom maps service API. I'm just in doubt if Python is enough for all the graphic stuff on the page (because usually you find JS there), and will it work fine with JS leaflet.